# Как произносить среднЕстатистический или среднИстатистический?

Tags: орфоэпия

Есть такие правила:

"Звук Е — а) в предударном слоге произносится ближе к е, обозначается условно еи:

сестра — сеистра,

весна — веисна;

б) в слабых слогах произносится как средний между е и и, обозначается знаком ь:

трепет — трепьт.

И конечно, правило про соединительные "о" и "е" в сложных прилагательных.

Чувство языка подсказывает, что надо средн**е**статистический.

Транскрипция указывает по другому [ˌsrʲedʲnʲɪstətʲɪˈsʲtʲit͡ɕɪskʲɪj]

Спасибо.